# IntervalSlider inside Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, user-interface

I try to implement a `Manipulate` control to draw a partial circle. For now, I have a `ParametricPlot` with fixed lower and upper bounds:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

What I am looking for is something like this (illustrative only, doesn't evaluate):

```
Manipulate[ 
   ParametricPlot[ {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, lower, upper} ],
   IntervalSlider[ {lower, upper}, ... ]
]
```

How can I connect the output of the `IntervalSlider` with `lower, upper`?

Comment: use `{{range, {0, \[Pi]}}, 0, 2 \[Pi], IntervalSlider}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ControlType -> IntervalSlider`.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, range[[1]], range[[2]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {{range, {0, \[Pi]}}, 0, 2 \[Pi], 
  ControlType -> IntervalSlider}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Control`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Control.html) to state quite concisely what you want with regard to `Manipulate` controls:

```
Manipulate[
   With[
      { 
         lower = int[[1]] * 2 Pi,
         upper = int[[2]] * 2 Pi
      }
      ,
      ParametricPlot[
         {Cos[t], Sin[t]},
         {t, lower, upper},
         PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
      ]
   ]
   ,
   Control[
     {
        {int, {0, 0.5}, "Interval [Rad]"},
        0, 1,
        ControlType -> IntervalSlider, 
        Method -> "Push", (* prevent crossing of sliders *)
        MinIntervalSize -> 0.1, (* prevent zero length intervals *)
        Appearance -> "Labeled"
     }
  ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 However, the options work with or without the explicit use of `Control` (at least in v12.3.1)

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, that is (once again) something I was not aware of.

Comment: Just as a personal preference: While you may omit `Control` I am rather old fashioned with regard to using the `Head` of an expression as a specific data type indicator. An expression like `Control[ ... ]` may work in more settings than a mere `List`?